# SQL query to get the data from student and marks table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Students` and `Books`

**Students**: sid (number), sname (varchar(3))

```
sid sname
---------
 4   abc
 2   def
 1   ghi
 3   jkl
```

**Books**: sid (number), book (varchar(1))

```
sid  book
---------
 3    a
 2    b
 2    c
 1    u
 4    d
 1    k
 3    p
 4    q
 4    k
```

Now, I want the output as shown below (sid, sname and the number of books read by each student)

```
sid sname count
---------------
 1   ghi    2
 2   def    2
 3   jkl    2
 4   abc    3
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: weren't any of your questions answered?

Answer (score 1):

Just join the two on `sid` column.

```
select s.sid, s.sname, count(b.book) cnt
from students s
left join books b
on s.sid = b.sid
group by s.sid, s.sname;
```

Comment: ` select sname,cnt 
from students s 
join (select sid, count(*) as cnt from books group by sid ) b
on s.sid=b.sid; `


Is it fine?

Comment: @Raaki You posted incomplete query in the comment but I get the idea. You want to first aggregate and then join. It's going to produce same result as the Students table has (or atleast should have) unique students (sid)

Comment: yeah just typo @GurV..now pls check the complete query

Comment: @Raaki That'll do the same thing as my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.sid,s.sname,count(book) as count 
from students as s 
join books as b 
on s.sid=b.sid 
group by s.sid,s.sname 
order by s.sid
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Comment: You can always edit this answer to add the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try This query once..

```
 select * into #student from(
 select 4   s_id,'abc' as name
 union all
 select 2   ,'def'
 union all
 select 1   ,'ghi'union all
 select  3   ,'jkl'
 ) as a

 drop table #student
  select * into #books from(

  select 3    s_id,'a' as book
   union all
 select 2    ,'b'
 union all
 select  2  ,  'c'union all
 select  1  ,  'u'union all
 select  4   , 'd'union all
 select  1    ,'k'union all
 select  3    ,'p'union all
 select  4    ,'q'union all
 select  4    ,'k'
 ) as a

 select * from #student
 select * from #books


  select s.s_id,s.name,COUNT(b.s_id) as[count] from #student s
  inner join #books b on b.s_id=s.s_id
  group by s.s_id,s.name
```

The Resultant output will be like

```
  +------+------+-------+
| s_id | name | count |
+------+------+-------+
|    1 | ghi  |     2 |
|    2 | def  |     2 |
|    3 | jkl  |     2 |
|    4 | abc  |     3 |
+------+------+-------+
```